# Windows Phone 7 solution can no longer be opened by Visual Studio 2012 after opening it in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013

I was developing a solution for Windows Phone 7 on my system using Visual Studio 2012. I installed Visual Studio 2013 and opened the solution with it. I found that Visual Studio 2013 won't let me build a Windows Phone 7 application, so I wanted to re-open the solution in Visual Studio 2012.

Now Visual Studio 2012 shows me the following error message:

> This project is incompatible with the current edition of Visual Studio

What do I need to do to 'undo' the changes made to my project in the upgrade process so that I can continue working in the older version of Visual Studio to finish my project?

Comment: What error message do you receive?

Comment: This project is incompatible with the current edition of Visual Studio.

Answer (score 1):

Visual Studio 2013 upgrades the project to the Windows Phone 8 SDK, and that is not compatible with Visual Studio 2012. If you are using a form of Source Control (Visual Studio Online, GitHub) you should roll back to the previous version. If not, Visual Studio (by default) creates a `_backup` folder under your solution where it will backup any files modified in the conversion process. Use these to return the project to its pre-visualstudio-2013-state.

Comment: I found the solution in `_backup` folder but VS2012 shows me the following error message `UNSUPPORTED ../../*.csproj`

Comment: You need to paste the `_backup` folder over the original solution. You can't open it as-is.